# C++ Recursive Variadic Lambda

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, lambda, c++14

In C++ we can have a recursive variadic template function. For example:

```
template<typename ...H>
void g(){}
template<typename H, typename ...T>
void g(H h,T ...t){
    std::cout << h << "\t";
    g<T...>(t...);
}
```

However this does not seem possible to be done using lambdas. My two main main concerns are:

- How to establish a base-case.
- How to make a lambda be recursive and at the same time variadic.

I know I can have recursive lambdas but can't see a way to make it variadic.
Is this type of feature only available in more high-level kind of languages such as Javascript?

Edit:
So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
template<typename C,typename H, typename ...T>
std::function<void(C,H,T...)> f=[](auto&&  self,H h,T ...t){
    std::cout << h << "\t";
    if(sizeof...(t)>0)
        self(self,t...);
};
```

Here the first argument would be the lambda itself.
However, the main issue is that in order to call this method I would to have define the type C, which I'm unsure on how to do (or even if it's possible).

Edit:
A more simplistic approach would be:

```
auto f = [] (auto&&  self, auto&& h,auto&&... t) {
    std::cout << sizeof...(t) << "\n";
    if( sizeof...(t)>0 ){
        self(self,1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    f(f,1,2,3,4,5,6);
    return 0;
}
```

However gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:55:13: error: use of ' [with auto:1 = &; auto:2 = int; auto:3 = {}]' before deduction of 'auto'
     self(self,1);
         ^
```

Comment: Part of the difficulty here is that lambda functions can't be overloaded without extra work, and overloading is the simplest way to handle a base case.

Comment: Do you really need recursion for your task? Maybe you could use fold expressions instead? (or dummy array trick, if C++17 is unavailable)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't think that question explains how to have a variadic argument.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can implement the problem using other strategies, but what I wanted to know if it was possible to do it this way (even if it's not ideal).

Comment: I don't think variadic lambdas make sense in C++ land? A lambda function is "named" by declaring a variable to reference it. A named variable has a fixed type, so can't be variadic, AFAI-can-see.

Comment: @Jodocus I don't think that question explains how to have a variadic argument.

Comment: @GemTaylor you can have variadic lambdas and recursive lambdas in C++. My question was if it was possible to combine them without taking into consideration if it would be a good idea or not.

Comment: OK, maybe c++14?

Comment: I'll add it as a tag. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++17 solves this problem with [Constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
#include <iostream>

auto f = [](auto&&... t){
    auto f_impl = [](auto& self, auto&& h, auto&&... t) {
      std::cout << sizeof...(t) << "\n";
      if constexpr ( sizeof...(t)>0 ){
        self(self,t...);
      }
    };
    return f_impl(f_impl, t...);
};

int main() {
    f(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

I also took the liberty of wrapping the first parameter(`self`) inside a "parent" lambda.

The problem with using `if(sizeof...(t))` as a guard is that, even if you will not call the lambda with improper arguments at runtime, the compiler still needs to compile the expression `self(self, t...)` with `sizeof...(t)==0`, which fails.

`constexpr if` solves this by making this check at compile-time, and not even compiling the block when the check yields `false`. Before C++17, conditional compilation semantics(excluding macros) could only be achieved using SFINAE or template specialization, both of which can't be done using only lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

I hate helpers, i think using helpers is a misleading design. That said, i couldn't find a solution to this without using a small helper.

The obstacles encountered here are the following:

- You cannot refer to a variable declared with `auto` within it's own initialisation expression

  *This is solved by passing the function as a parameter to itself using an inner lambda to provide a clean public interface*
- You cannot use `if( sizeof... )` as a guard (or any other "runtime" mechanism) for the "base-case" because you would still have a call to a function that cannot accept that number of parameters within that `if` block, which doesn't compile

  *This is solved by "overloading the lambda" and actually defining all the needed function overloads (i.e the "base-case" also)*
- You cannot "simply" overload a lambda once it is defined

  *This is solved by using a "small" helper code*

All in all, one solution could be this:

```
#include <iostream>

/////////// Helper

template<class F, class... Fs>
struct overloaded : F, overloaded<Fs...>
{
  using F::operator();
  using overloaded<Fs...>::operator();

  overloaded(F&& f, Fs&&... fs)
    : F(std::move(f))
    , overloaded<Fs...>(std::move(fs)...)
  {}
};

template<class F>
struct overloaded<F> : F
{
  using F::operator();

  overloaded(F&& f)
    : F(std::move(f))
  {}
};

template<class... Ts>
overloaded<Ts...> overload(Ts&&...lambdas)
{ return overloaded<Ts...>{std::move(lambdas)...}; }

///////// Recursive Variadic Lambda

int     main(void)
{
  auto lambda = [](auto... args)
    {
      auto lambda_impl = overload(
        [](auto self)
        {
        },
        [] (auto self, auto first, auto...rest)
        {
          std::cout << first << std::endl;
          self(self, rest...);
        });

      lambda_impl(lambda_impl, args...);
    };

  lambda(4, "lol", 8.3);
}
```